# Linear subspaces dimensions (2)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question:

> $U$ and $V$ are two linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^7$, with $\dim(U) = \dim(V) = 5$.
>
> What is the minimum dimension of $U ∩ V$?

---

Using the Grassmann Formula I have:

$\dim(U ∩ V) + \dim(V + U) =  \dim (U) + \dim(V)$

$\dim(U ∩ V) + \dim(V + U) = 5 + 5 = 10$

$\dim(U ∩ V) = 10 - \dim(V + U)$

So to answer I have to find the maximum dimension of $\dim(V + U)$.

Because $V + U ⊆ ℝ^7$, the max dimension is $7$. So:

$\dim(U ∩ V) = 10 - \dim(V + U) = 10 - 7 = 3$

Is this right? If yes, are there other ways to solve it?

Comment: Yes, what you say is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. By Grassmann's formula,
$$
\dim(U\cap V)=\dim U+\dim V-\dim(U+V)
$$
so it is minimal when $\dim(U+V)$ is maximal. Since it is possible that $\dim(U+V)=7$ (an example would be needed), but not more, the minimum value for $\dim(U\cap V)$ is $5+5-7=3$.

Comment: Is it correct to say `V + U ⊆ ℝ⁷`?

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ Yes, of course. However, you need to point out that $U+V=\mathbb{R}^7$ is possible: take $U=\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5\}$ and $V=\{e_3,e_4,e_5,e_6,e_7\}$.